# JOptionPane halts after a random number of run (using Eclipse Kepler, java 7, Windows 7 64bit on MacbookAir)

Tags: crash, windows-7-x64, joptionpane, halt, eclipse-kepler

I have researched thoroughly on this problem but no use. Hopefully you guys can help me. Thanks very much in advance!

The test code is below:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class JOptionPane_Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String userExit="a";
        while (userExit!=null){
            userExit = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Message");
        }
    }
}
```

It simply displays an input box waiting for user's response, repeats if user hits OK, and stops if user hits Cancel or X button. The box halts after a random number of hitting OK (or Enter Key). It only shows the frame of the box, with the X button, and nothing inside (no message, no input field, no ok or cancel button). The only thing I can do is hitting the X button to exit out of the program.

It happens with both showMessageDialog and showInputDialog.

My log shows this warning:

> !SESSION 2013-07-09 14:00:12.666 -----------------------------------------------
>   eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.I20130605-2000
>   java.version=1.7.0_25 java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader
>   constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US Framework arguments:
>   -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2013-07-09 14:00:30.147
>   !MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path
>   "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level Git
>   settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under
>   the native Git installation directory. The most important of these
>   settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this
>   parameter to true in this system level configuration. The Git
>   installation location can be configured on the Team > Git >
>   Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab. This warning
>   can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings
>   preference page.

but I suspect that this warning does not have anything to do with the JOptionPane error. Or am I wrong?

I found on this [forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-684511.html) that someone had exactly the same problem I have, and the solution was to check on the compiler that Eclipse uses, making sure it's Sun's instead of GCJ. However, mine has always been Sun's, java 7.

I have tried both Eclipse for 64 and 32 bit.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!!! Thanks to [Nick](http://www.objectdefinitions.com/odblog/2008/joptionpain-joptionpane-hidden-behind-always-on-top-window-crashes-swing-ui/comment-page-1/#comment-74970)
Instead of using a null parent component, I add my panes to a frame, and everything worked! It's apparently a JOptionpane bug.

Reworked code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class JOptionPane_Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String userExit="a";
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        while (userExit!=null){
            userExit = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Message");
        }
    }
}
```